# Rails routes - using associated model attribute as route root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a user that signs up and logs in.

Right now their route is rails standard "user/3".

A user belongs to an organization. An org has many users.

I want all users for that org, when they sign in, to have the url http://mysite.com/:organization name.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this...

First add a method to your organization model to show name instead of id in url

```
def to_param
    name
end
```

and update your routes as required, and functionality also to show the users of that organization

Organization Controller..

```
def show
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:organization])
  @users = @organization.users
end
```

Redirect user to user organization show path after login.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your authentication is setup or what you're using to handle your authentication, but presumably when a user logs in successfully you just change the redirection in your log in action. Something like:

`redirect_to user.organization`

instead of `redirect_to user`

Answer (score 1):

You need to browse on nested resources.  Please look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

UPDATE: more appropriate answer

I think this is more for your scenario http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope

Comment: Their example for nested resources is magazines/:magazine_id/article/"id. I was looking for ":organization_name/whatever" where organization name changes depending upon the user.organization